# Show data only to those users who are added in a table

Tags: php, mysql

First thing is that user create event(college event) lets say `TechTo` in his account and he can only access that created event using the below query

```
$sql_created=mysqli_query ($dbconfig,"SELECT * FROM events 
WHERE userID='".$_SESSION['userid']."'")  or die( mysqli_error($dbconfig));
```

Now what am trying to achieved is that, I have another table name `event_coordinators` in which the user who created the event `TechTo` want to add coordinators in `event_coordinators` table and then the user added in `event_coordinators` table can also control `TechTo` created event and can edit delete about event

This is `event_coordinators` table in which coordinators are added

```
coID    addBy   addedUserID     eventID
1        1        3              2
2        1        11             3
3        1        11             2
```

This is `events` table where user creates events 
Here `events.userID=event_coordinators.addBy`

```
eventID     userID  eventName   
  2           1     Mind Sparx  
  3           1     Tech Vision
```

How can i achieved kind of select statement or another way to do for above situation

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "this kind of query". A statement to insert a row to `event_coordinator`?  A statement that "can edit delete about event"? Or were you meaning a SELECT statement? The only information we have about the `events` table is that it contains a column named `userid`. With no definition of `events` table, no example data, and no sample of the desired resultset, we're just guessing what you are attempting to achieve.

Comment: Yeah sorry for not being informative for that question but i edited the above question so that it can be understand in better way and i m new to stack overflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you need something along these lines:

```
select distinct events.*
from events
left join event_coordinators ec on ec.eventName = events.name
where events.userID  = {$_SESSION['userid']}
   or ec.addedUserID = {$_SESSION['userid']}
```

Note that it would be simpler to add an index on the events table and store that in event_coordinators instead of joining on the string event name, especially if the event name might not be unique.

Comment: yes i have eventID of the events table but for understanding i renamed it to string

Comment: Right, but the standard approach would be to store the event ID in the event_coordinators table, and then using the query above as an example, you'd be able to get the human-readable text from `events.name`.  The database should only need to store the human-readable version in one place.

Comment: this is working man for all the list of events

Answer (score 0):

Going by what I've read, you're adding let's say "event A" into a database as user 1.
User 1 has all permissions to edit/remove event A.
You want to add User 2 to the event coordinators so they can also edit and remove event A?

In which case,
I'd do something like

```
$uid=$_SESSION['userid'];
$sql=mysqli_query($dbconfig, "SELECT eventName FROM event_coordinators WHERE addedUserID='{$uid}'");
if(mysqli_num_rows($sql)) {
    echo "You are a co-ordinator of the following events:";
    while($r=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
        echo "<a href='event.php?event=".$r['eventName']."'>".$r['eventName']."</a><br />";
    }
}
```

In the above sample, I've checked the number of rows that the query has returned, there's no point executing a fetch array if there aren't any rows that match your query.

On the event page, or where you'd like to edit the event or display controls of the event, you could do a query like

```
$uid=$_SESSION['userid'];
$event_name=$_GET['event'];

$sql=mysqli_query($dbconfig, "SELECT eventName FROM event_coordinators WHERE addedUserId='{$uid}' AND eventName='{$event_name}'");

if(mysqli_num_rows($sql)) {
   //User has access to this event
} else {
   //User couldn't be found, therefore no access to this event.
}
```

Comment: so you mean to say that their is no way to do with the select statement ?

Comment: Could you elaborate? That is a select statement

Comment: yeah i think this is what I need to use on main page rather then on the event list page thank you

Comment: The first code sample will display a list of events that an added user coordinator can access, and the second code sample is to be used on an editing page or viewing page for a specific event

Comment: Unless you've designed your system so that the creator of an event is automatically added to the `event_coordinators` table, you probably want that second query to include events that the user is coordinator for (which it does) _and_ events that the user has created (which it does not).

Comment: yeah thank you i get that now thank you